# Add node into XML if another node doesn't exist

Tags: xslt-2.0

I am new to XSLT and working on transformation from one XML to another and facing below issue

If Book 1 node exist then I should not see Book 2 node into transformed XML. I tried different phrases but doesn't work.

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Catalog>
  <book1>Wise Otherwise</book1>
  <book2>Great Expectations</book2>>
</Catalog>
```

Expected XML
    
    
       Wise Otherwise

Below is my XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:if test="book1">
    <xsl:template match="book2" />
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="not(book1)">
    <xsl:template match="book2">
    <book2>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </book2>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:if>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I even tried xsl:Choose

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="/catalog/book1">
     <xsl:template match="book2" />
</xsl:when>
<!-- more xsl:when here, if needed -->
<xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:template match="book2">
    <book2>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </book2>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Book1 and Book2 are mutual exclusion from transformed xml.

Book2 should be in transformed XML if and only if Book1 is not in input XML.

I hope this will give you better picture

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a stylesheet with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and the template `<xsl:template match="Catalog[Book-1]/Book-2"/>`.

Based on your provided XML sample a complete XSLT stylesheet is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalog[book1]/book2"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which transforms

```
<Catalog>
  <book1>Wise Otherwise</book1>
  <book2>Great Expectations</book2>
</Catalog>
```

into

```
<Catalog>
  <book1>Wise Otherwise</book1>

</Catalog>
```

Comment: Appreciate your response, but this doesn't give me expected result      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" indent="yes"/>
 
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
 <xsl:template match="Catalog[Book1]/Book2"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: @user3495155, please edit your question and put minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT, wanted result, result you get in there so that we can understand and reproduce the problem. Reading code samples in comments is a bit difficult and we need to see the XML as well.

Comment: Hello Martin, I have updated my comments as advised.

Comment: @user3495155, I have edited the answer and shown a complete and working XSLT sample.